# How do I rotate a rectangle of latitude and longitude?

Tags: geometry, rotations, geodesic

I have a rectangle with its corners specified in latitude and longitude. I would like to rotate it about it's centre a certain number of degrees. I was using longitude as an x value and latitude as a y value but I realized that the rotation is actually on the surface of a sphere instead of a plane so might be inaccurate. Is there a formulate to do the rotation and give the new latitude and longitudes.

Comment: This is not really a rectangle since it's on the surface of a sphere. So how do you find the center? Is it the point of intersection of the great circles that pass through "diagonally opposite corners"? If so, then how do you rotate it? Recoordinatize the sphere so that this center is a pole, and rotate it around the pole?

Comment: Compute the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of the vertices, rotate about the centre point and convert back to latitude & longitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question really has nothing to do with “rectangles”, which @MPW has already pointed out don’t exist on a sphere. There is a way of looking at your problem that makes it an exercise in basic spherical trigonometry, and I’ll show you that. I do not make any claim that it’s the fastest way of getting your problem solved, though.

You have a point, let’s say $R$, on the sphere, let’s say it’s Richmond, and you want to rotate it about a fixed point $O$, let’s say that’s Orono. And your motion is a “rotation” in this sense: you have the “heading” $\alpha$ from $O$ to $R$, that is the compass-direction that you start out in if you’re going in a great-circle path. And you have the distance $d$ from $O$ to $R$. Your rotation asks for the location that you’ll get to if you go a distance of $d$ with an original heading of $\alpha+\delta$, where $\delta$ is the angle that you’re rotating things.

Now let’s draw a picture, you’ll have to do the drawing yourself. Knowing the latitude and longitude of Richmond and Orono, you see that there’s a triangle with vertex way up at the north pole $P$. The distance from $P$ to $O$ is Orono’s colatitude, that’s just the complement of Orono’s latitude. I’ll call this $c_O$. Similarly, you have the colatitude of Richmond, I’ll call this $c_R$. So you see that you have a triangle $RPO$ with legs $c_R$ and $c_O$, and up at the pole, the angle is the *difference* between the two cities’ longitudes. I’ll call this $\lambda$, to keep Greek letters for vertex angles and Latin lower-case for lengths of sides, capital letters for points on the sphere.

So you see that you have a SAS situation, and just as in plane trigonometry your first tool to use is Law of Cosines, to get the third side of your triangle, that’s the distance from $O$ to $R$, which I’ve called $d$. Then there’s also a spherical Law of Sines for getting the vertex angle $\alpha$ at $O=\,$Orono.
The general Laws of Cosines and Sines are
$$
\cos c=\cos a\cos b+\sin a\sin b\cos\gamma\,,
$$
for Cosines, where $\gamma$ is the angle opposite the side of length $c$. And for the Law of Sines,
$$
\frac{\sin a}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{\sin b}{\sin\beta}=\frac{\sin c}{\sin\gamma}\,,
$$
where I’m sure you’ve guessed that $\beta$ is to be the angle opposite the side $b$ and $\alpha$ is the angle opposite the side $a$.

Now for our setup of rotating Richmond about the center Orono: We have our two legs $c_R$ and $c_O$ and our longitude-difference $\lambda$, so we get
$$
\cos d = \cos c_R\cos c_O + \sin c_R\sin c_O\cos\lambda\,.
$$
Now, with $d$ and $\lambda$ in hand, a side-and-opposite-angle pair, you can use Sines to get $\alpha$. Now add your rotation-angle $\delta$ to get $\alpha'=\alpha+\delta$, and to find your Richmond$'$, you use the triangle $POR'$, where $PO$ is still $c_O$, and $OR'$ is still $d$, but the known vertex angle now is at $O$, and it’s $\alpha'$. You see that it’s quite a megillah, but certainly very easily programmed.